# spring Unsatisfied dependency expressed...sometimes

Tags: java, spring

When I try to declare this simple bean:

```
<bean id="file" class="java.io.File" c:child="foo.txt" c:parent="\tmp" />
```

I get:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.io.File]: Ambiguous constructor argument types -
>   did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

Ok, ok... I get it. I can try to use indexes on my constructor arg. I see that as the de facto answer. What I don't get, is if I have a similar class (for demonstration):

```
public class MultipleConstructors {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private int c;
    private Object d;

    public MultipleConstructors(String a, String b) {
        this(a, b, -1, null);
    }

    public MultipleConstructors(String a, String b, int c) {
        this(a, b, c, null);
    }

    public MultipleConstructors(String a, String b, int c, Object d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

I **can in fact** declare it in the same way as the File declaration and Spring let's me. Both of these work... but why?

```
<bean
id="multipleConstructors1"
class="sandbox.spring.MultipleConstructors"
c:a="testing"
c:b="testing, hello"
c:c="123"/>

    <bean
id="multipleConstructors2"
class="sandbox.spring.MultipleConstructors"
c:a="testing"
c:b="testing, hello"
/>
```

Is it because the File class is not instrumented somehow? e.g. MultipleConstructors is a local source file, vs. the other is in the jdk?

Comment: How are you compiling your `MultipleConstructors` class?

Comment: Just with maven compiler plugin.

Answer (score 2):

*Is it because the File class is not instrumented somehow*

Yes. The JDK was probably compiled in a way that did not preserve the parameter names. You can confirm this by running, for example,

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(File.class.getConstructor(String.class, String.class).getParameters()));
```

If this prints

```
[java.lang.String arg0, java.lang.String arg1]
```

then the parameter names are not present in the `.class` file used to run your program.

The parameter names are therefore not available to Spring and so these two

```
c:child="foo.txt" c:parent="\tmp"
```

can't be mapped reliably to the underlying parameters. Spring can convert from a `String` value to a `File` object, so two `File` constructors are applicable. Spring can't choose which one to use.

This is not the case with your own class, which you're probably compiling in a way that preserves the parameter names. Or if you're not, then the arguments you've provided deterministically map to a constructor.

For example, only one constructor can be applied to

```
c:a="testing"
c:b="testing, hello"
c:c="123"
```

this one

```
public MultipleConstructors(String a, String b, int c) {
```

and only one can be applied to

```
c:a="testing"
c:b="testing, hello"
```

this one

```
public MultipleConstructors(String a, String b) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way to instrument the class files to pick up on it based on the source? The funny thing is, the Spring tools in Eclipse seem to recognize the constructor arg names and suggests them. But it fails at runtime.

Comment: @javamonkey79 So Eclipse, with Maven, actually downloads the source, so you can browse it. However, at runtime, the non-source jars are provided on the classpath. If those weren't compiled with access to the parameters, you're out of luck.

Comment: the getParameters method does not appear to be present as you've described

Comment: Oh, that is only available since Java 8. Previously, I think Spring uses byte code analysis to get the parameter names, if they're present.